# Is it correct to use while-loop to report progress and completion?

Tags: java, android, zip4j

I have added `zip4j` library to my Android project. It is very easy to use.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(downloadedFilePath);
zipFile.extractAll(context.getFilesDir().getPath());
```

But there is one feature that I am concerned about. Instead of subscribing to get the progress of unzipping, they use `while-loop` as follows:

```
while (pm.getState() == ProgressMonitor.STATE_BUSY) {
    // my progress handler is here
}
```

And if I need to know that unzip is complete, I should use it as follows:

```
while (pm.getState() == ProgressMonitor.STATE_BUSY) {
    // the loop runs until progress monitor changes its status
}
if (pm.getResult() == ProgressMonitor.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
    // my code to handle completion
}
```

To me it looks as anti-pattern and poor coding. Should I use in my project, or switch to a different zip-library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while` loop will use CPU resources and keep it busy. i would suggest use `Thread` and sleep it for a while and then again check `pm.getState()` and update your progress bar

Answer (score 1):

It's  better to use `AsyncTask` for this kind of task.

Start showing progress on `onPreExecute`, extract the files in `doInBackground`, and dismiss the progress in `onPostExecute`.

You can also use `onProgresUpdate` to show the exact progress of the work.

This will also ensure that the extraction work happens in a background thread, and will keep the UI thread free.